# How to use pg_search with globalize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, internationalization, pg-search, globalize

I use a pg_search gem for searching in my rails app. The main model in my app was:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_everywhere, against: [:author, :title, :description]
end
```

It worked perfect with

```
@books = Book.search_everywhere(params[:search])
```

in index action of BooksController. Then I added gem 'globalize':

```
  translates :title, :author, :publisher, :description, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true
```

And now searching is not working.

```
Book.search_everywhere(params[:search])
```

can't find any field.
Anybody used pg_search gem with globalize gem?

Comment: `is not working` - what does it mean???

Comment: search_everywhere  can't find any field.

Answer (score 0):

I have found correct solution:
Gem 'globalize' created new table "book_translations". So I should search in this table:

```
#book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  has_many :book_translations
  translates :title, :author, :publisher, :description, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true
  pg_search_scope :search_everywhere, :associated_against  => {:book_translations => [:title, :author, :description]}
end

#book_translation.rb
class BookTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create BookTranslation model. Here is more simple solution:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  translates :title, :author, :publisher, :description, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true
  pg_search_scope :search_everywhere, :associated_against  => {:translations => [:title, :author, :description]}
end
```